# Запуск подпрограммы в web-приложении Java

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

Есть *Web* приложение, которое работает на *Tomcat*. Так же есть другое приложение, консольное, запускаемое через `main` метод. И одно, и второе приложения содержат *DAO* слой, использующий *Hibernate*. Сущности в обоих приложениях одинаковы, и при добавлении новой в одно из приложений требуется его дублировать на втором, что не очень удобно.

Я бы хотел объединить эти два приложения в одно, чтобы у них был общий пакет сущностей и *DAO* слоя, общий пул соединений hibernate. Я не уверен, что это возможно, так-как *Web* приложение в моем понимании работает по факту прихода *Request* на *Servlet*.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализуема ли такая схема?

P.S.

Нагуглил, что можно использовать [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791986/background-thread-for-a-tomcat-servlet-app), это может быть выходом?

Comment: tomcatee? Тогда вроде можно разместить на сервере ejb, к которому можно подключаться клиентом как локальным, так и удаленным. В этом ejb понаделать методов какие нужны обоим клиентам. Сами же поставили тэг java-ee, вот и смотрите в этом направлении. ee для этого и задумано. Как раз из DAO сделайте этот ejb.

Answer (score 1):

Да, listener это нормально. Чаще конечно используется для инициализации веб-приложения. Но никто не запрещает в listener создать поток или таймеры, которые будут потом что-то делать. Тут зависит от того что вы хотите сделать.

Если функционал, который реализует консольное предложение запускается/используется вручную, то можно также смотреть в сторону:

- MBeans (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/)
- Управлять через сервлет (добавить сервлет при вызове которого будет происходить запуск функционала)
- Страничку с кнопками на JSP или через сервлет (вариант предыдущего пункта)