# Hibernate в отдельном потоке Web-приложения

Tags: многопоточность, java-ee, hibernate, tomcat

Имеется web-приложение на Tomcat. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471996/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-web-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-java) я спрашивал, как запустить в отдельном потоке некоторую логику, работающую в бесконечном цикле. Было решено в  ServletContextListener запускать отдельный поток, в котором реализовывать нужные действия. У меня в этом потоке в бесконечном цикле с задержкой в 5 секунд создается новый поток, в котором открывается сессия Hibernate и что-то там делается. Проблема в том, что при каждой попытке открыть такой поток я получаю исключения вида

`Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.postgresql.core.v3.Portal]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.`

Хотя вся работа потока проходит без ошибок. Как устранить эту проблему?

```
     @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

            //Запускаем в отдельном потоке тикер почтовой очереди 
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //Задержка тикера - 5 секунд
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

                            try {   
                              sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
                              //Здесь что-то происходит
                              sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
                              } catch (StaleObjectStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                              } catch (Throwable e) {
                                try {
                                    if (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                                        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                                    }
                                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                }
             }).start();
        }
```

Comment: Это может быть связано с повторным развёртыванием вашего приложения - перед возникновением ошибки вы не делали обновление приложения без перезапуска сервера? Возникает ли ошибка после "чистого" старта сервера Tomcat?

Comment: К сожалению, возникает и после рестарта.

Comment: @carapuz, я думаю вам нужно написать логику по прерыванию вашего цикла и ожидания завершения всех текущих активных потоков в `contextDestroyed`. При запуске сервлета до первого undeploy (или остановки Tomcat) исключение появлялось?

Comment: Самому интересно стало, поэтому вопрос-  можно ли это все заменить на другой контейнер c ejb и вместо создания потоков использовать @Schedule  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу сразу как минимум три проблемных момента:

1. У вас плодятся потоки, причем иерархия ветвистая: поток слушателя (`ServletContextListener`) порождает поток таймера ("*тикер почтовой очереди*") который в свою очередь порождает потоки для работы с БД. Ссылки на потоки нигде не хранятся, что **теоретически** может вносить еще больше неопределённости - у сервисов могут быть затруднения с тем, чтобы определить источник, запустивший потоки. Можно попробовать сохранять ссылки, например, ссылку на тикер сохранить в слушателе. Можно попробовать подключить какой-нибудь сервис управления задачами, запускаемыми по расписанию (например, [Quartz](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-quartz-2-example/)). Можно попробовать применить средства Java для управления пулами потоков и их очередями.
2. Вы используете `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, который для того, чтобы определить где тот самый Current Session, скорее всего опирается на информацию о текущем потоке. Возможно, что у него получается сделать это корректно, а возможно что и нет (см. п.п. 1).
3. Я не вижу нигде в коде высвобождения ресурсов, попробуйте добавить блок:

   ```
   finally {
     if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
       session.close();
     }
   }
   ```

Плюс можно попробовать вместо `getCurrentSession()` использовать `openSession()`, это может помочь в отвязывании сессии от разбора текущей иерархии потоков.