# Hibernate ошибка работы с БД в новом потоке

Tags: java, многопоточность, hibernate

Связка Hibernate + Spring.

Вызываю метод контроллера, в этом методе в новом потоке запускаю метод сервиса для обновления таблицы в БД.

Первый поток сразу прекращает свою работу (метод контроллера возвращает ответ, что все ок, заполнение таблицы стартовало).
Второй поток в цикле начинает заполнять данными таблицу БД.
Ф-ция слоя DAO для записи данных в таблицу следующая:

```
@Repository
public class AreaDAO extends BaseDAO<Area> {
    public AreaDAO() {
        super(Area.class);
    }

    public void updateArea(Long areaId, Long regionId){
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("update Area set region_id =:region_id"+
        " where id=:id and coalesce(is_deleted,0)<>1");
        q.setLong("region_id", regionId);
        q.setLong("id", areaId);
        q.executeUpdate();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

После пары итераций (пара записей в таблице все-же обновилась) на методе `q.executeUpdate()` происходит зависание и обновление таблицы БД прекращается.

После продолжительного подвиса в логах сервера появляется ошибка: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

Если же весь код я запускаю не в отдельном потоке, а в потоке метода контроллера, то таблица БД обновляется без проблем.
В чем может быть проблема такого поведения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас выполняется DML-операция, но нет кода открытия и завершения транзакции. Из-за того, что вы работаете в отдельном потоке, скорее всего, транзакционность не может управляться контейнером прозрачно в этом случае, и надо делать это вручную. Попробуйте добавить `transaction = session.beginTransaction()` и `transaction.commit()` вокруг `q.executeUpdate()`. Также, следует сделать корректное освобождение ресурсов, т.к. сейчас это сделано неверно.
Оберните код в try/catch и добавьте блоки:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    finally {
      if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
      }
    }
```

После этих манипуляций, у вас могут возникнуть ошибки связанные с тем, что ручное управление транзакциями может не поддерживаться в вашем окружении. Но это отдельная тема и отдельный вопрос. Если проблема возникнет, можете начать её разбор с этого ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486577/183597